# AWS File Gateway - Ensure Authentic UID/GID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

AWS File Gateway seems to allow setting of UID/GID NFS permissions on shares and files in the gateway. This is great, but since there is no local user base stored on the gateway itself, it seems like, once authenticated (which seems to go against the client's user store, not some File Gateway user store), the UID and GID valued seem to be populated by the client, not the server. This invalidates any kind of security as far as I can tell. Anyone that knows a UID or GID for a share could set the local computer's UID/GID accordingly and gain access to that share with whatever password they want.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I misunderstanding here?

Only that this has always been a limitation of NFS: the client machines are trusted.

There's a built-in assumption in NFS that users with privileged access to a client machine are trusted users, and therefore no user would have an account with a conflicting or unauthorized UID/GID.

In an environment where that isn't the case, your observation is correct... the basic NFS security model doesn't provide meaningful security if the client machines can't be trusted.

Comment: so there's no way to have authentication occur server side in NFS?

Comment: It is technically possible for server side authentication to occur in NFS v4 and v4.1, but not v3.   Storage Gateway supports 3 and 4.1 and doesn't implement authentication for 4.1. For comparison, Elastic File System (EFS), which only speaks NFSv4.1, does not implement user authentication, either.  The trust models are based on allowing connections from specific hosts by IP, essentially requiring that the connecting machines be trusted.  File modes and permissions are enforced, of course, but this requires a trustworthy UID/GID from the client in order to be meaningful, as you have observed.